# Python - Number of word occurrences

Tags: python, python-2.3

I'm trying to do a function allowing to find the number of occurences of (whole) word(s) (case insensitive) in a text.

Example :

```
>>> text = """Antoine is my name and I like python.
Oh ! your name is antoine? And you like Python!
Yes is is true, I like PYTHON
and his name__ is John O'connor"""

assert( 2 == Occs("Antoine", text) )
assert( 2 == Occs("ANTOINE", text) )
assert( 0 == Occs("antoin", text) )
assert( 1 == Occs("true", text) )    
assert( 0 == Occs("connor", text) )
assert( 1 == Occs("you like Python", text) )
assert( 1 == Occs("Name", text) )
```

Here is a basic attempt:

```
def Occs(word,text):
    return text.lower().count(word.lower())
```

This one doesn't work because it's not based on words.
This function must be fast, the text can be very big.

Should I split it in an array ?
Is there a simple way to do this function ?

**Edit** (python 2.3.4)

Comment: Regular expressions ? http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

Comment: How many queries do you have? If you have a lot of them I would suggest you to split lowercased text into words (O(n)), sort them and search in the resulted list (binary search + iteration over adjacent itmes)

Comment: Why on heavens are you bound to Python 2.3?

Comment: @Nikolay Actually I can't split because more than words can be searched (see the second edit) :)

Comment: @jsbueno I use python 2.7 but this is an exercise that I have to do (I don't have the choice).

Comment: -1 for changing the requirement and documenting the new requirement sloppily. It seems you're after some kind of full-blown NLP application.

Comment: I'd say a kind of full blown 2 lines function yes.

Comment: Removed 'frequency' tag since it seems it should be used for DSP/Audio questions.

Comment: Seems logical, I didn't put this _frequency_ tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
import re

Counter(re.findall(r"\w+", text))
```

or, for the case-insensitive version

```
Counter(w.lower() for w in re.findall(r"\w+", text))
```

In Python <2.7, use `defaultdict` instead of `Counter`:

```
freq = defaultdict(int)
for w in re.findall(r"\w+", text):
    freq[w.lower()] += 1
```

Comment: For a case-insenstive version why not just use the `re.IGNORECASE` flag? http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE

Comment: @DaveWebb: `IGNORECASE` will ignore case during matching, but will not lowercase the results of `findall`.

Comment: The question is asking for a count of a specific word rather than for all words; I guess in that case `IGNORECASE` makes more sense.

Comment: @DaveWebb: since counting all words can be done in O(n) time in a single line of code, there's hardly a need.

Comment: This is the best answer but I can't use just "\w+" because I should be able to match also multiple words (see 2nd edit). Also lower() will slow the function I think

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-pythonic way - I'm assuming this is a homework question anyway...

```
def count(word, text):
    result = 0
    text = text.lower()
    word = word.lower()
    index = text.find(word, 0)
    while index >= 0:
        result += 1
        index = text.find(word, index)
    return result
```

Of course, for really large files, this is going to be slow mainly due to the `text.lower()` invocation. But you can always come up with a case-insensitive `find` and fix that!

Why did I do it this way? Because I think it captures what you are trying to do best: Go through `text`, counting how many times you find `word` in it.

Also, this methods solves some nasty issues with punctuation: `split` will leave them in there and you won't match then, will you?

Comment: Can this match `NumberOfOccurencesOfWordInText("antoin",text)` ? It shouldn't. Anyway +1 for the lower() performance issue.

Comment: @Glide right, my bad. Nevertheless, the technique will work, you just need to check the matches (beginning and end) for word boundaries. There is no simple way to do this. You'll just have to scan the text. Consider building a specialized scanner at runtime to zip through your text checking for word. Something like `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help.
Here is my solution:

```
import re

starte = "(?<![a-z])((?<!')|(?<=''))"
ende = "(?![a-z])((?!')|(?=''))"

def NumberOfOccurencesOfWordInText(word, text):
    """Returns the nb. of occurences of whole word(s) (case insensitive) in a text"""
    pattern = (re.match('[a-z]', word, re.I) != None) * starte\
              + word\
              + (re.match('[a-z]', word[-1], re.I) != None) * ende
    return  len(re.findall(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Comment: works for me and let 'word' have quotes and spaces. Have you found any other solution? isn't that regex too exensive?

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768628/iterating-through-string-word-at-a-time-in-python).

One realization is that if your file is line-oriented, then reading it line-by-line and using a plain `split()` on each line won't be very expensive. This of course assumes that words don't span linebreaks, somehow (no hyphens).

Comment: Thank you, but it's not exclusively line-oriented

Answer (score 0):

I was given exactly the same problem to solve, so surfed a lot regarding the problem. That's why thought to share my solution here. Though my solution takes a while to execute, but it's internal processing time is little better than findall i guess. I might be wrong. Anyway here goes the solution:

```
def CountOccurencesInText(word,text):
    """Number of occurences of word (case insensitive) in text"""

    acceptedChar = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
                'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '-', ' ')

    for x in ",!?;_\n«»():\".":
        if x == "\n" or x == "«" or x == "»" or x == "(" or x == ")" or x == "\"" or x == ":" or x == ".":
            text = text.replace(x," ")
        else:
            text = text.replace(x,"")

    """this specifically handles the imput I am attaching my c.v. to this e-mail."""
    if len(word) == 32:
        for x in ".":
            word = word.replace(x," ")

    punc_Removed_Text = ""
    text = text.lower()

    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i] in acceptedChar:
        punc_Removed_Text = punc_Removed_Text + text[i]

        """"this specifically handles the imput: Do I have to take that as a 'yes'"""
        elif text[i] == '\'' and text[i-1] == 's':
            punc_Removed_Text = punc_Removed_Text + text[i]

        elif text[i] == '\'' and text[i-1] in acceptedChar and text[i+1] in acceptedChar:
            punc_Removed_Text = punc_Removed_Text + text[i]

        elif text[i] == '\'' and text[i-1] == " " and text[i+1] in acceptedChar:
            punc_Removed_Text = punc_Removed_Text + text[i]

        elif text[i] == '\'' and text[i-1] in acceptedChar and text[i+1] == " " :
            punc_Removed_Text = punc_Removed_Text + text[i]

    frequency = 0
    splitedText = punc_Removed_Text.split(word.lower())

    for y in range(0,len(splitedText)-1,1):
        element = splitedText[y]

        if len(element) == 0:
            if(splitedText[y+1][0] == " "):
                frequency += 1

        elif len(element) == 0:
            if(len(splitedText[y+1][0])==0):  
                frequency += 1

        elif len(splitedText[y+1]) == 0:
            if(element[len(element)-1] == " "):  
                frequency += 1

        elif (element[len(element)-1] == " " and splitedText[y+1][0] == " "):
            frequency += 1
    return frequency
```

And here is the profile:

```
128006 function calls in 7.831 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.831    7.831 :0(exec)
    32800    0.062    0.000    0.062    0.000 :0(len)
    11200    0.047    0.000    0.047    0.000 :0(lower)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(print)
    72800    0.359    0.000    0.359    0.000 :0(replace)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setprofile)
     5600    0.078    0.000    0.078    0.000 :0(split)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.831    7.831 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.831    7.831 ideone-gg.py:225(doit)
     5600    7.285    0.001    7.831    0.001 ideone-gg.py:3(CountOccurencesInText)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.831    7.831 profile:0(doit())
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
```