# Counting occurences of words that appear in a list using Python

Tags: python

I have appended excel sheet values to a list using xlrd. I called the list a_master. I have a text file with words that I want to count the occurrences of that appear in this list (I called this file dictionary and theirs 1 word per line). Here is the code:

```
with open("dictionary.txt","r") as f:
for line in f:
    print "Count " + line + str((a_master).count(line))
```

For some reason though, the count comes back with zero for every count word that exists in the text file. If I write out the count for one of these words myself:

```
 print str((a_master).count("server"))
```

It counts the occurrences no problem.I have also tried

```
print line
```

in order to see if it is seeing the words in the dictionary.txt file correctly and it is.

Comment: Could you provide the example of the file?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742732/python-number-of-word-occurrences

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: Not an exact duplicate. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines read from the file is terminated by newline character. There may also be white space at the end. It is better to strip out any whitespace before doing a lookup

```
with open("dictionary.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print "Count " + line + str((a_master).count(line.strip()))
```

**Note** Ideally, searching a list is linear and may not be optimal in most cases. I think [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is suitable for situation as you depicted.

Re-interpret your list as a dictionary where the key is the item and the value is the occurrence by passing it through `collections.Counter` as shown below

```
a_master = collections.Counter(a_master)
```

and you can re-write your code as

```
from itertools import imap
with open("dictionary.txt","r") as f:
    for line in imap(str.strip, f):
        print "Count {} {}".format(line, a_master[line])
```

Comment: @Danny: If this answers your question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: One more question actually. In order to count occurrences of words in the list, I split up each word in the list. But what if i wanted to count the occurrences of "software defined networking". How would i go about doing this? Would i need to rewrite how that sentence appears in the dictionary.txt file? My txt file has a mixture of both single words as well as sentences.

Comment: @Danny: Your second question is too complex to be answered in the comment box. I would suggest you to post a new question and someone may want to answer it. Just to brief you here, search for trie and prefix tree. That might be the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import re
import collections
words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('dictionary.txt').read().lower())
collections.Counter(words)
```

Why is this question tagged xlrd by the way?